# How can I test multi-part uploads with FlaskClient (for unit testing)

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug, http-method

The docs don't talk much about these, just basic params with PUT/POST/GET/DELETE, but I have a multipart upload that accompanies PUT, how can I do test it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer my own question:

```
builder = EnvironBuilder(method='POST', data={'foo': 'this is some text',
...      'file': (StringIO('my file contents'), 'test.txt')})
```

Since TestClient is a wrapper around EnvironBuilder, just extend the data dict with a file key, value, and then wrap the file object as a StringIO.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How did you use the EnvironBuilder to get the response? Would it be the same for uploading other kinds of files? For example: jpeg images.

Comment: @primpap is this the same for images?